# How can I detect which version of webOS is running on a TV

Tags: javascript, webos

I need to patch a functionality just for webOS 1.x.

Which would be the better approach? I'm not sure about the user agent in old versions, and Luna service is unreliable on webOS 1.0.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I've managed using luna. Here is the snippet:

```
var lunaReq= webOS.service.request("luna://com.webos.service.tv.systemproperty",{
method:"getSystemInfo",
parameters:{
"keys": ["modelName", "firmwareVersion", "UHD", "sdkVersion"]
},
onSuccess: function (args) {
console.log("sdkVersion: ", args.sdkVersion);
//for 3.3: sdkVersion:  3.3.0
//for 2.: sdkVersion:  2.2.0
}
},
onFailure: function (args) {
console.log("Error calling LUNA service");
}
});
```

luna service can give problems on first webos versions, but user agent is completly inconsistent. I found all kind of user agents for webOS 1.x:

Mozilla/5.0 (webOS/1.3; U; en-US) AppleWebKit/525.27.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/1.0 Safari/525.27.1 Desktop/1.0

Mozilla/5.0 (webOS/1.3; U; en-US) AppleWebKit/538.39.41 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/1.0 Safari/538.39.41 Desktop/1.0

Mozilla/5.0 (Web0S; Linux/SmartTV) AppleWebKit/537.41 (KHTML, like Gecko) Large Screen WebAppManager Safari/537.41

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks! was about to try using the user-agent